# Cross-thread issue accessing a windows form control from other class

Tags: multithreading, winforms, ssis

I am executing a SSIS package from a windows form. In a button click of the form, I am executing the SSIS package and instantiating the PackageEventListener passing "this" which is the Form1.

```
var app = new SSISApplication();
_pkg = app.LoadPackage(pkgLocation, null);
var listener = new PackageEventListener(this);
DTSExecResult pkgResults = _pkg.Execute(null, null, listener, null, null);
```

I am also overriding DefaultEvents to get the progress from the package in the PackageEventListener.cs class. In the constructor I get the Form1 and use that to get to the public method that sets the lblExportStatus label.

```
public class PackageEventListener : DefaultEvents
{
     private Form1 formInstance;
     public PackageEventListener(Form1 form)
     {
        formInstance = form;
     }

     public override void OnProgress(TaskHost taskHost, string progressDescription, int percentComplete, int progressCountLow,int progressCountHigh, string subComponent, ref bool fireAgain)
     {
          var message = string.Format("{0}:{1}", percentComplete, progressDescription);   
          formInstance.SetMsg(message);
          base.OnProgress(taskHost, progressDescription, percentComplete, progressCountLow, progressCountHigh, subComponent, ref fireAgain);
     }
}
```

I would like to update a label in the windows form with the message from OnProgress method.

I created a public method inside the windows form to set the label as follows:

```
public void SetMsg(string msg)
{
   if (lblExportStatus.InvokeRequired)
       lblExportStatus.Invoke(new System.Action(() => lblExportStatus.Text = msg));
   else
       lblExportStatus.Text = msg;
}
```

I get this error: The thread '' (0x3930) has exited with code 0 (0x0).

The lblExportStatus never gets assigned with the value inside SetMsg method. InvokeRequired is always true. And an exception is thrown "An exception 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Debugger.Runtime.CrossThreadMessagingException' occurred".

Please help with this issue. Thank you in advance!!

Comment: The message you are getting implies that the thread has completed successfully.

Comment: "The thread '' (0x3930) has exited with code 0 (0x0)" is not a error. Please post the stack trace if you think that it is.

Comment: That's a horribly roundabout way to invoke a simple action. Just call `lblExportStatus.Invoke(new Action(() => lblExportStatus.Text = msg));` inside your `SetMsg(...)` method.